# Use different methods with same open connection c#

Tags: c#

I have a class connection in C# and differents methods. The method connect get three arguments.

I need to use the connection Open() in the method `inserirFornecedor` but there is an error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

```
  public Boolean connect(String user, String password, String BD) {

        connectionSql = new SqlConnection(
            "user id=" + user + ";" +
            "password=" + password + ";" +
            "Server=" + BD + ";" +
            "Database=****;" +
            "Connection timeout=30"
            );

            try
            {
                connectionSql.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Ligação estabelecida com o Servidor! ", "Ligação");
                return true;

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Falhou a ligação!", "Ligação" + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

    }

    //Metodo para inserir fornecedor na base dados.
    public void inserirFornecedor(string codigo, string nome, string entrega, int qos, int tsq, int qtd) {


            commandSql = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO supplierschedule VALUES(@codigo,@nome,@entrega,@qos,@tsq,@qtd)", connectionSql);


            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", codigo);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrega", entrega);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qos", qos);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsq", tsq);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qtd", qtd);
            commandSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: You are using a not initialized SqlConnection object in your inserir function.

Comment: what i need is use the connection.open() of the method connect inside the method inserirFornecedor

Comment: Insufficient information and code. Looks like you may have 2 connectionSql objects, or a sequence error or ...

Answer (score -1):

Change you code to

```
public SqlConnection connect(String user, String password, String BD)
    {

        connectionSql = new SqlConnection(
            "user id=" + user + ";" +
            "password=" + password + ";" +
            "Server=" + BD + ";" +
            "Database=****;" +
            "Connection timeout=30"
            );

        try
        {
            connectionSql.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Ligação estabelecida com o Servidor! ", "Ligação");
            return connectionSql;

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Falhou a ligação!", "Ligação" + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }

    //Metodo para inserir fornecedor na base dados.
    public void inserirFornecedor(string codigo, string nome, string entrega, int qos, int tsq, int qtd)
    {

         using (SqlConnection conn = connect(user, password, BD))
        {
            if (conn == null) return;//Cannot connect to DB
            commandSql = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO supplierschedule VALUES(@codigo,@nome,@entrega,@qos,@tsq,@qtd)", conn);


            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", codigo);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrega", entrega);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qos", qos);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsq", tsq);
            commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qtd", qtd);
            commandSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `user`, `password` and `BD` are not defined in `inserirFornecedor`

Comment: Capture this parameter and pass to the  method, are you new to c# or programming? This are the three parameter your connect method needs.

Comment: Yes, i am new in C# programming

Comment: "capture this parameter"? no, I am not. You have still posted uncompilable code.

Comment: When i use the method inserirFornecedor, i need the all information about method connect, user name, password and the name of database, for to insert values in the database.

Comment: as mentioned by Default, this code does not compile. An option is to have user, password and BD as private class variables, and initialise them through the constructor.